# How to see the source code of a built-in function?

Tags: source

I want to see the source code of the function `other-buffer`.
When I use `M-x`- `xref-find-definitions`, Emacs shows:`visit tags table (default TAGS)`. Then I press `RET`, Emacs shows:`File /TAGS does not exist`. 
What should I do if I want to see the source code? 
I'm reading an introduction book and I got stuck with the expression:
`(other-buffer (current-buffer) t)` 
This is why I want to see the source code. And this is my second day learning Emacs.

System: macOS

Comment: Are you on Linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: @nephewtom MacOS

Comment: Honestly, if you are an Emacs newcomer, I would not recommend starting with its C source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've compiled your Emacs you have to download the C source code separately. If you're on GNU, some distros allow downloading the source code using the package manager, which makes upgrading a bit easier. For example [here's a tutorial for installing the source code on Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/can-i-install-a-programs-source-as-a-package/4202/6).

Once you have the source code tree in a directory, say `~/src/emacs-27.1/src`, add

```
(setq find-function-C-source-directory (concat "~/src/emacs-" emacs-version "/src"))
```

to your init.el. The `(concat "~/src/emacs-" emacs-version "/src")` bit evaluates to `"~/src/emacs-27.1/src"` (assuming your Emacs is version 27.1), so you don't need to update this setting when you upgrade Emacs. The variable `find-function-C-source-directory` stores the directory Emacs looks into for the C source files (see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `find-function-C-source-directory`).

---

Since you're on MacOS I can't suggest anything in particular but to try

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emacs.git
```

That should get you the full source tree. Place it on a directory of your choice and set `find-function-C-source-directory`, then both `xref-find-definitions` and links in `describe-function`/`describe-variable` (`C-h f`/`C-h v`) and should work.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the way to do that is to type M-x describe-function in the minibuffer, then enter other-buffer. That will show you a help window on the function with the documentation on that function. At the top is usually a link to the source code of the function you can click on to get there. `other-buffer` is implemented in the C source code though so you unless you installed emacs from source you probably can't get to it this way.

Comment: There's been discussion about *always* installing the C-sources precisely for this use case. Disk space is cheap after all (but the distributions would probably just strip it out again <sigh>)

Comment: See also `M-x find-function RET`.